# SweetAlert is rendering if its hidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

there is some component which is using SweetAlert from "react-bootstrap-sweetalert".

Problem that if "show" property is false than SweetAlert should not be rendered
but in my case it is rendering anyway and the function inside SweetAlert is calling everytime no matter if its hidden or not.

here is some example:

```
someFucntion = () => {
    console.log('TEST');
};
render() {
    const { showAlert } = this.state;

    return (
      <span>
        <SweetAlert
          show={showAlert}
          confirmBtnText="OK"
          title=""
          onConfirm={this.confirm}
          onCancel={this.cancel}
        >
          {this.someFunction()}
        </SweetAlert>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rendered because you told it to render.
If you dont want to render it then you need to surround it with a ternary.
Something like this:

```
{showAlert && 
<SweetAlert
      show={showAlert}
      confirmBtnText="OK"
      title=""
      onConfirm={this.confirm}
      onCancel={this.cancel}
    >
      {this.someFunction()}
    </SweetAlert>
}
```

Pay attention as you'll probably won't have the animation you would expect as the popup isn't rendered to the DOM so he will just show up.
If you're looking not to call the function, just surround it with a ternary.

```
{showAlert && this.someFunction()}
```

This will call the function only when the popup is visible.

Comment: that's right but then for what we need this "show" property ? according to documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sweetalert "if show=false, the alert will not be rendered."

Comment: The component really isnt rendered according to the source code it just returns false whenever you pass it show=false.
The problem is that you are calling the function on the render and it is being called before it tries to render the component. 
As the children are rendered before the parent is rendered.